# Which kind of functions satisfy this property?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces

We look to the Banach space $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ with the well-known norm on it and the weak-*-topology (which is in fact locally convex), hence $f_n\rightarrow f$ in the weak *-topology iff $\int\limits_{[0,1]}{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\cdot|g(x)|\ dx}\rightarrow0$ for each $g\in L^1([0,1])$. I want to characterize the functions with the following properties:

1. The limit $\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$ exists in the weak-*-topology
2. $||\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}||<\infty$ for all $t>0$

Is the space which contain the functions with this propertie something like $W^{1,\infty}$ with some extra properties? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you wrote is not equivalent to weak$^*$ convergence in $L^\infty$.  Consider, for example, $f_n(t) =  \sin (2\pi nt)$.

Comment: What did you really mean to write in (2)?

Comment: I think you don't  need the property (2) since 1 is satisfied , and these properties dosn't meet convergence in l^\infty , may it's agree with local theorem of probability measure function the kind of function you need , as i see in ur first part of definition (dominated convergence theorem) , pleas look sheft's theorem

Comment: :  -  (         $\!\!  \;\!  \;\!  \;\!  \;  \;$